# DroidText image only works if I convert it to a JPEG

Tags: android, pdf

In my app I'm making a pdf.  This pdf needs a bitmap that I generate.  This code works:

```
        document.open();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        bmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG ,
                100 , stream);
        Image jpg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
        jpg.scalePercent(71, 71);
        document.add(jpg);
```

Unfortunately converting to JPEG loses a lot of quality.  I tried to convert it to PNG, like this:

```
        document.open();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        bmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG ,
                100 , stream);
        Image jpg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
        jpg.scalePercent(71, 71);
        document.add(jpg);
```

But this just generates a PDF which can't be opened.  The code seems to run fine, I went through with debugger and stream seems to have an image inside.  What is going on?

Comment: What does 71, 71 stand for?

Comment: I have to scale the image by that amount to fit properly.  It doesn't really stand for anything.  I know I shouldn't use random constants like that, but you know how it goes....

Comment: x and y scale percentages